# MYSQL select rows starting from a random number

Tags: mysql

I want to select 30 rows (in serial order) from anywhere in the middle of the table. 
I am trying to do it by adding a column '`serial`' having unique `auto_increment` serial numbers. 
My code is:

```
SELECT * FROM A2 
     WHERE serial>(
         SELECT ROUND(RAND()*(
              SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A2))
) LIMIT 30
```

The part `(SELECT ROUND(RAND()*(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A2)))` is working perfectly i.e. generates a random number from 1 till the number of rows in the table, but the complete query is not working. It throws rows that are not in serial progression, and it almost always throws first row having serial below 30.

Can someone help me to write this query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, assuming your serial starts at 0; if it starts at 1, just replace `>=` with `>`.

```
SELECT A2.*
FROM A2 
JOIN (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (SELECT COUNT(*)-29 FROM A2)) serial) b
WHERE a2.serial >= b.serial
ORDER BY a2.serial
LIMIT 30;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d2cc/1).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM A2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 30
```

This will pick 30 random rows.

Comment: [Be aware of the consequences though](http://www.webtrenches.com/post.cfm/avoid-rand-in-mysql).

Comment: There was a mistake in my question. I want them in a serial order. Just edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Append `ORDER BY serial` like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A2 
WHERE serial > (
    SELECT ROUND(RAND() * (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A2))) 
ORDER BY serial
LIMIT 30;
```

Also you probably need to use `FLOOR` instead of `ROUND` and subtract 30 from upper limit like this:

```
WHERE serial > (
    SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A2) - 30)))
```

Otherwise you may get less then 30 rows when random is close to the end of the table.

Sorry.  That answer was wrong.  Here is what works for me:

```
SELECT a2.*
FROM a2, 
    (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a2) - 30)) AS r) AS r 
WHERE a2.serial BETWEEN r.r AND r.r + 29;
```

Comment: @user1517108 Are you sure that any serial values between those values actually exist in the table?

Comment: Yup... I browsed the table to make sure

Comment: @user1517108 It was my fault.  Added fixed variant.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do this

```
SELECT * FROM A2 
WHERE serial > (
    SELECT ROUND(RAND()*(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A2))
) 
ORDER BY serial
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: This solution also doesnt Work.